# Google Play Services 6.5.+ APIs white screen

Tags: android, google-play-services

My application runs successfully when using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

But when I switch to using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

The application immediately displays a white screen and then an ANR.

This is gradle console log after a clean and build:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for <app1> as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, guess I'm sticking to 6.1 for a while

Answer (score 2):

By any chance do you use Google Analytics? I recently found https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82157 which seems to be the same issue as me. If this is the case you could try [Google Analytics blocks Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533679/google-analytics-blocks-android-app/27542483#27542483)

Answer (score -1):

In 6.5 you don't need to import every submodules of the play services anymore
[Check this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html) ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would suppose one of the class/method has changed since the time you implemented it. Maybe try a full clean/rebuild and post your logcat