# Android Google Analytics on OSX failed, but doesnt with Lenovo Windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, google-analytics

I've got two laptops: A lenovo yoga 2 pro (Eclipse with Windows 8) and Macbook Pro (Eclipse with Yosemite).
I've got an android app with Google Analytics.

When I launch my app with eclipse from my Lenovo, it works perfect.

But, when I launch the **SAME CODE** from my macbook pro (With eclipse too), my android app freezes (Obviously with no traces from LogCat...) and I get BlackScreen..

Finaly, If I remove analytics code from my android app, the code doesn't freeze and works perfectly.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533679/google-analytics-blocks-android-app/27871161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as related here: [Google Analytics blocks Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533679/google-analytics-blocks-android-app/27871161), remove this code on manifest and it will work:

```
<meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />
```