# E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-analytics

I recently started adding Google Analytics integration into my Application. To do so I've been following the steps provided here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

I had no Application class so I created one with the basic implementation provided here:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android.html

In each Activity I added the following snippets:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //Stop the analytics tracking
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    //...
}
```

and I started seeing live users on my corresponding Analytics page.

For whatever reason when I start the App via fresh install from Android Studio it works fine. However when I kill the app through the task manager and start it again it displays only a blank screen and provides the following error.

```
E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 36489: Ljava/lang/ReflectiveOperationException;.printStackTrace ()V
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11845: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11842: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11848: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9471: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 565: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 587: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
```

I feel like I'm missing something super basic here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I looked through some of the related issues on Stack Overflow and it doesn't look like any cover my current case.

I'm using play services version `65870000` and have the following two lines added to my manifest:

```
<!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<!-- Google Analytics Version v4 needs this value for easy tracking -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
    android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

My current test device is a LG Lucid 2 (vs870) running Android 4.1.2

If there's any other code snippets I should include, please feel free to ask.

**Note**: I checked out my previous tag and this issue is not present so it must be related to creating this Application class, `src/main/res/xml/app_tracker.xml` and `src/main/res/xml/global_tracker.xml` config files and adding required analytics setup code in activities.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

**Edit**: If I remove the following lines from my MainActivity the app starts up properly every time again:

```
// onStart
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
// onStop
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
// onCreate
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

Comment: Have you change the application class to be your MyApplication by setting the name attribute of application element in your ApplicationManifest.xml? It should looks something like this:
<application name="<your package>. MyApplication"> ...

The log lines you provided show that someone is trying to process the call stack. This someone is likely Google Analytics trying to send a crash report caused by ((MyApplication) getApplication()). Just a wild guess....

Comment: I think those lines were not actually causing the ANR. See my answer below. There was a bug in the Analytics SDK itself that was causing the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Bug in Google Analytics SDK causes an ANR when using XML for GA global configuration. AKA you can't use this Meta tag:

```
<!-- Google Analytics Version v4 needs this value for easy tracking -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
    android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

See this amazing answer for more:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542483/740474